# RedirectToAction / CanvasRedirectToAction Giving 404 Error Because Virtual Directory Name is Repeated in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, facebook-c#-sdk

I am just getting started with ASP.Net MVC 3 with the Facebook C# SDK. I've had pretty good luck so far, but I am having an issue when returning RedirectToAction or CanvasRedirectToAction in a Controller method.

When I click either the *Submit* or Create New_ button in the view below, I always get send to
***/app**/app/Event/Create* instead of *app/Event/Create*, resulting in a 404

Thanks in advance!

**EventController:**

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,user_events,create_event")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,user_events,create_event")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,user_events,create_event")]
    public ActionResult Persist()
    {
       return this.CanvasRedirectToAction("Index", "Event");
    }
```

**Event/Create.cshtml**

```
    @using Facebook.Web.Mvc

    @model App.Models.Event

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Persist", "Event")) {
    @Html.FacebookSignedRequest();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Event</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            @Html.CanvasActionLink("Create New", "Persist")
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

Comment: well your in the same controller simple return RedirectToAction("[actionname]"); will do the job    but you have an endless loop  you are having the action Persist  redirect to Persist  !

Comment: you're right I made some mistakes putting the code up... I've tried doing that as well without any luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear like it's easily possible. My guess is that the javascript that looks at the URL in the frame within the C# SDK doesn't do a good job of creating the correct path to redirect to. I just got rid of the virtual directory to solve the problem for now.